# When should we use [AnyHashable] instead of [Any]?

Tags: arrays, swift, hashtable

I have been converting objective c classes to swift. I noticed that most of the conversion tools convert (NSArray*) to [AnyHashable] not [Any]. I was wondering why should they use type-erased value instead of plain Any.

Comment: Do you really need to have more than one object type inside your collection? You would be better using collections with a single element type. Generally you won't need `AnyHashable`unless you are using different object types as dictionary keys.

Comment: That makes sense.